# Add properties instead replacing them in tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, pgfkeys, tikzset

I am working on a project involving several files and i would like to have the possibility to add properties to styles using `tikzset` and `pgfplotsset`.

I reduced my code to a MWE :

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\tikzset{
    Asymp/.style={densely dashed,very thick,green},
    LieuReel/.style={ultra thick,red},
    Asymp/.style={blue},
}%draw=none
\pgfplotsset{
    Bode/.style={
        axis x line=bottom,axis y line = left,
        xmax=\Wmax, xmin=\Wmin,
        axis line style = very thick},
    GaindB/.style={ylabel=$G_{dB}$},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} % Inverses
        \def\Wmax{10^(3)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-3)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}
            [Bode,GaindB,ymin=0,ymax=70]    
            \addplot [LieuReel,samples=100,domain=.001:1000] {(10*(log10(10^2*x^2+1)))+20 } ;
            \addplot [Asymp,samples=100,domain=.001:1000] {20*(log10(10*x)) } ;
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces a plot and for the second curve a style `Asymp` in defined in the `tikzset`. It is defined twice because I would like to change the color but you can see I am loosing the other properties (`densely dashed,very thick`)

The answer : "Put it all in one definition" does not interest me, because I want to be able to add properties across different files.

Can you help ?

[image: plot of two curves]

Comment: You can use `.../.append style=...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatGPT told me, use :

```
 \tikzset{Asymp/.append style={blue}}
```

Comment: [Tutorial.](https://tikz.dev/tikz-scopes#sec-12.4.2) [Full reference.](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys)

Comment: Here's the `pgfkeys` documentation for the `.append` and `.append style` directives: [Link](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#sec-87.4.5)

Comment: As amusing as it is to cite ChatGPT, it is better to cite reliable sources such as the manual, as Qrrbrbirlbel and MentatOfDune do.